# Run-time error 2471 The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: 'Add' when using two dlookups

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am getting issue when I use two dlookup statments to check whether the user has permission to edit or Add record. Following is the script. The error comes with Dlookup for ADD statement:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If (DLookup("Edit", "QryUserAction", "UserName = '" & [TempVars]![UserName].[Value] & "' And FormName = '" & Me.Name & "'")) = False Then
    Me.btnEdit.Enabled = False

Else

    Me.btnEdit.Enabled = True
End If
If (DLookup("Add", "QryUserAction", "UserName = '" & [TempVars]![UserName].[Value] & "' And FormName = '" & Me.Name & "'")) = False Then
    Me.btnAdd.Enabled = False

Else

    Me.btnAdd.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there `Add` field in `QryUserAction`? What exact error's text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD is a JET reserved word. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html

This is likely causing confusion.

Should not use reserved words as names for any objects. If you do, then enclose in [ ]. `"[Add]"`

Also advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Could simplify code. Assuming Edit and Add are yes/no type fields and a yes/no field can never be Null, the DLookup should never return Null as long as there is a match to criteria. Null will cause "Invalid use of Null" runtime error so deal with that possibility.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Me.btnEdit.Enabled = Nz(DLookup("Edit", "QryUserAction", "UserName = '" & [TempVars]![UserName].[Value] & "' And FormName = '" & Me.Name & "'"), False)
Me.btnAdd.Enabled = Nz(DLookup("Add", "QryUserAction", "UserName = '" & [TempVars]![UserName].[Value] & "' And FormName = '" & Me.Name & "'"), False)
End Sub
```

Comment: on top of that, Dlookup returns null if there's no match found, not False. = False at the end of the Dlookup should be dropped and **Me.btnEdit.Enabled = False** and **Me.btnEdit.Enabled = True** should be swapped. Bracket around Dlookup is reduntant.

Comment: If `QryUserAction` returns no rows, would not `Dlookup` be `Null`?

Comment: See revised answer.